# Composer rest server can't connect to ca.org1.example.com

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I followed [this tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) to setup `myorg/composer-rest-server` and everything was working fine till I import card but when I make a GET request to `/api/system/ping` it returns 500 Error:

```
{"error":{"statusCode":500,"name":"Error","message":"Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]","stack":"Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]\n    at client.getUserContext.then.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:393:34)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)"}}
```

So I checked the logs for rest container, it can't seem to find 127.0.0.1:7054. Here is the error log.

```
Unhandled error for request GET /api/system/ping: Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]
at client.getUserContext.then.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:393:34)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

So I checked the logs for the container `ca.org1.example.com`, and it is listening to port 7054

```
2018/04/01 09:57:25 [DEBUG] CA initialization successful
2018/04/01 09:57:25 [INFO] Home directory for default CA: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2018/04/01 09:57:25 [DEBUG] 1 CA instance(s) running on server
2018/04/01 09:57:25 [INFO] Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7054
```

I think i need to change 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 but not sure how to do it the right way. Could also be a firewall issue?
Here's my `.composer/cards/restadmin@myserver/connection.json`

```
{"name":"hlfv1","x-type":"hlfv1","x-commitTimeout":300,"version":"1.0.0","client":{"organization":"Org1","connection":{"timeout":{"peer":{"endorser":"300","eventHub":"300","eventReg":"300"},"orderer":"300"}}},"channels":{"composerchannel":{"orderers":["orderer.example.com"],"peers":{"peer0.org1.example.com":{}}}},"organizations":{"Org1":{"mspid":"Org1MSP","peers":["peer0.org1.example.com"],"certificateAuthorities":["ca.org1.example.com"]}},"orderers":{"orderer.example.com":{"url":"grpc://orderer.example.com:7050"}},"peers":{"peer0.org1.example.com":{"url":"grpc://peer0.org1.example.com:7051","eventUrl":"grpc://peer0.org1.example.com:7053"}},"certificateAuthorities":{"ca.org1.example.com":{"url":"http://ca.org1.example.com:7054","caName":"ca.org1.example.com"}}}
```

I'm using AWS EC2

- OS:  Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS,
- Docker:   17.12.0-ce,
- Composer: v0.19.0
- Fabric:   v1.1

Answer (score 0):

Which card have you imported?  If it is the restadmin card, I think you may have imported a Card containing an expired One-Time secret.  After the rest admin card was used to start the REST server (in the container) the secret was replaced with certificates - so if you export the restadmin card again with a different name `composer card export -c restadmin@trade-network -f restadmin-cert.card` you will see that it is a larger file because of the certificates.  You should be able to import and use this new .card file.

(If you were using a different card e.g. jdoe - did you run the sed command for this card to correct the addresses?)